# Findstr : not getting the correct output

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, findstr

Here is my batch file:

```
cmdkey.exe /list > "%TEMP%\List.txt"
findstr.exe Adobe "%TEMP%\List.txt" > "%TEMP%\adobeonly.txt"

for /f "tokens=2-3 delims= " %%G in ("%TEMP%\adobeaonly.txt" ^| findstr "Adobe Photoshop Subscription") do Set AdobeSub1=1
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%G in ("%TEMP%\adobeonly.txt" ^| findstr "Adobe Photoshop Subscription #2") do Set AdobeSub2=1
```

Text file looks like (adobeonly.txt):

```
Target: LegacyGeneric:target=Adobe Photoshop Subscription #2
Target: LegacyGeneric:target=Adobe Photoshop Subscription
```

the findstr command gets always the two lines I cant make difference between the first line and the second line.

Can somebody helpme with that issue.

PS: Sorry for my english.

Comment: You do not specify a search string but multiple (space-separated) search expressions. To define a search expression containing spaces, use the `/C` option of `findstr`…

Comment: It doesn't work. If I have one line in the text file say "Target: LegacyGeneric:target=Adobe Photoshop Subscription #2" I get for the 2 variables True. as output.

Comment: You don't need findstr.exe, just use find.exe instead.

Comment: Replace the `"tokens=delims="` with `delims="`, then *findstr **/e /L /C:**"Adobe ..."* since one string is a substring of the other. The extra flags are `/e` line ends with; `/L` literal, not regex (probably not necessary) and `/C:` contiguous string. Note that the colon `:` is *required*

Comment: thanks for your input but its not working.